# Error in VisualForce page after adding parameter to RemoteAction method

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an angularjs application running in a VisualForce Page. It was running fine but when I added a parameter to one of the methods I get an error on startup. Error: Error when loading a VisualForce page.

The original method is:

```
global static Patient__c CreateNewPatient(String HospitalID, String LastName, String FirstName, String MedicalRecordNumber, String DateOfBirthString, String Gender, String SocialSecurityNumber, String PatientNumber, String AccountNumber, String Race, String Language, String Email)
```

and then I change it to this (without changing anything else):

```
global static Patient__c CreateNewPatient(String HospitalID, String LastName, String FirstName, String MedicalRecordNumber, String DateOfBirthString, String Gender, String SocialSecurityNumber, String PatientNumber, String AccountNumber, String Race, String Language, String Email, String s)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it will be better if you add only one single string parameter and you pass a json from the client side. On your apex controller you deserialize the json string to a map<string, object> or a custom wrapper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states that `RemoteAction` methods must be uniquely identified by name and number of parameters. So adding one more parameter probably makes it unrecognizable as the same function.

If your original method is:

```
global static Patient__c CreateNewPatient(String HospitalID, String LastName, 
String FirstName, String MedicalRecordNumber, String DateOfBirthString,
String Gender, String SocialSecurityNumber, String PatientNumber, String AccountNumber, 
String Race, String Language, String Email) { /* code goes here*/ }
```

What you could do is add your new parameter, but also add a backwards-compatibility overload matching the original signature that points to the expanded method:

```
global static Patient__c CreateNewPatient(String HospitalID, String LastName, 
String FirstName, String MedicalRecordNumber, String DateOfBirthString,
String Gender, String SocialSecurityNumber, String PatientNumber, String AccountNumber, 
String Race, String Language, String Email) { 
  return CreateNewPatient(HospitalID, LastName, FirstName,
    MedicalRecordNumber, DateOfBirthString, Gender, SocialSecurityNumber,
    PatientNumber, AccountNumber, Race, Language, Email,
    'some default value for s');
}
```

Then refactor all your VF to use the new parameter.

Incidentally though, seeing as this method has so many parameters, I wonder if you might be better advised to use a wrapper class parameter or such.

Comment: Thanks! Both answers help explain the issue. I like the idea of passing a json object as that works well from the javascript client.